# Relation between dot product and magnitude of vector product

Tags: vectors

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two vectors in $\mathbf R^3$. Calculate the angle between the two given vectors if $A \cdot B= \left| A\times B\right|$.

Please guide me how to find the answer of the above problem.

Comment: Welcome to this site! This site is for posting your mathematical questions to get answers, not for posting your mathematical tasks (or assignments) to have someone do them for you. What have you tried? What is it that you don't understand? Once this is clear to you, you can ask a precise question (notice that your post does not contain a question, just an "order" to perform a task).

Comment: @Pierre-Guy Plamondon: I edited to "guide" and "how to" ! but as you said a lot needs to be done in OP :)

Comment: @AlphaE True :) But I feel that something is still lacking, and that my comment is still relevant.

Comment: @AlphaE I agree with Pierre-Guy. Merely massaging the language of a request to make it a little more "polite" does little or nothing to improve the quality of a question. I usually don't even bother, even if I am editing a question for other reasons (e.g., to fix bad formatting).

Answer (score 2):

$A.B=|A||B|cos{\theta}=|A\times B|=|A||B||sin{\theta}|\implies |sin{\theta}|=cos{\theta}\implies {\theta}=45^0. $